# Implement a Finder-like treeview and representing its nodes with lazy loading using NSOutlineview

Tags: cocoa, treeview, lazy-loading, finder, nsoutlineview

When implement a big file system tree in NSOutlineview, it lacks an event notification when user click the left side down arrow triangle icon of a node. This is very important when lazy-loading a large amount of file nodes into a directory node and represent it into NSOutlineview. Otherwise, developer have to load entire directory into it, in this way, the loading will force end user to wait, this is not acceptable. In short, current version of NSOutlineview can't implement lazy-loading caused by this issue. Does anyone meet this issue or have an alternative solution to implement a Finder-like treeview with Cocoa NSOutlineview, any help will be great appreciate.

### In Addition:

NSOutlineview does not emit an outlineViewItemWillExpand event when click the icon, and there still lacks enough info to get which node will expand even that event emitted, [NSOutlineview selectedRow] can't work because the node which will be expanded have not been selected yet.

Comment: Take a look at the [TableViewPlayground sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010727).

Comment: Please post your code of `outlineViewItemWillExpand(_:)`. The user info of the notification should contain the item.

Comment: Thank you @Willeke for the sample link, I know it, but the point is "implement lazy-loading".  The problem is that even outlineViewItemWillExpand() called but you still can't get which node the clicked icon belongs to. Ideally, click the icon of a directory node then outlineViewItemWillExpand() should be called each time, but in fact, it not, practically.

Comment: Please note, Mr. Willeke, it is click the left side down arrow icon not the node.

Comment: In TableViewPlayground lazy loading is implemented by the data model, not by `outlineViewItemWillExpand(_:)`. If you want help debugging `outlineViewItemWillExpand(_:)` then post a [mre] please.

Comment: Hi, Mr. @Willeke, thank you for your response, but you still got nothing what the issue is. You can click the down arrow icon then its node will be expanded, at this point, lazy-loading called, but the node can't be selected by the click. There is no such issue when double-click a node and then call lazy-loading. This issue can be resolved by hittest maybe, i.e. test which icon clicked and which node it belongs to, but that will increase complexity.

Comment: What is the issue? Is it how to implement lazy loading? Or is it `outlineViewItemWillExpand(_:)` is not always called when an item will expand? Or is it getting the item from the notification?

Answer (score 1):

I load my child nodes in the following call in `NSOutlineViewDataSource`:

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        guard let node = item as? Node else { return false }
        return node.children.count > 0
    }
```

The `children` property of my `Node` class is lazy, and hence forced to load here.

This method is only called on Nodes that are visible in the outliner. This way you are only loading one layer ahead of the visible tree. The disclosure triangle (expand arrow) will then be visible if children exist.

If you have an efficient way to know the number of children a node has without actually loading them, then it may be better just to return the child count in `outlineView(_: isItemExpandable:)` and then do the actual load in `outlineViewItemWillExpand(_:)` as Willeke has suggested in the comments.

Comment: Or do the actual load in `outlineView(_:child:ofItem:)`.

Comment: Yes, Mr. @Willeke, 
do the actual load in outlineView(_:child:ofItem:) works, issue resolved, thank you very much, but sorry I can't mark an accepted answer for you.

Conclusion
------
1, isItemExpandable() is simple, if the node is directory then return YES.
2, in numberOfChildrenOfItem() fetch count of child nodes if it is directory and at the first loading.
3, in outlineView(_:child:ofItem:) do the same as 2 to implement lazy loading.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. @ Willeke, adopt your suggestion works. but I can't mark an accepted answer for you, could you make one?